# How to call DoDataExchange on child dialogs in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dialog

I am following this article:

[Creating embedded dialogs in MFC](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4408/Creating-embedded-dialogs-in-MFC)

I have got it compiling in my test project but I have one issue. At the end of the article it states:

> One final point to note that even though it is not in the code, from within `CEmbeddedDialogDlg::DoDataExchange` you should call both the `m_dlg1` and `m_dlg2` `DoDataExchange` methods.

At the moment I have:

```
void CMFCApplication3Dlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TAB1, m_ctlTab1);
}
```

My three child dialog `DoDataExchange` methods don't seem to be available? I noticed in all three instances of the child dialogs that this function has a access of `protected` which should likely remain like that. So what is the correct way to call `DoDataExchange` on the child dialogs?

Comment: Normally you just need to call `UpdateData()`.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou So inside my parent dialog, in `DoDataExchange` I call `m_dialog1.UpdateData();`?

Comment: Haven't ever done it but I would first try calling the parent's `UpdateData()`. If this doesn't work (and you want to get data from all children with one call), maybe override the parent's `UpdateData()`: call the inherited one and then (or before maybe) call the children's `UpdateData()` (with the same `bSaveAndValidate` parameter of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I made a test and I would propose the solution below. My initial suggestion in the comments of "overriding" `UpdateData()` was wrong because this function is not virtual. Probably you called `UpdateData()` in your code (in `OnOK()`) but this calls the "new" one, which is not an override. Sorry for the inconvenience.

For my testing I created a "child" dialog in a "parent" dialog - not a tabbed one, but it should work in your case as well. Especially tested the validation (DDV) case, with the classic MFC error handling (displaying a message-box, focusing the control causing the problem and stopping - not the most modern and user-friendly UI setup, but the one MFC uses). The goal is to have `UpdateData()` returning `FALSE` if validation (for either the child or the parent dialog) fails, so that the default implementation of `OnOK()` won't close the (parent) dialog. In my proposed solution I call `UpdateData()` for the active child dialog in the parent dialog's `DoDataExchange()`. I do not call `DoDataExchange()` instead, because the `pDX` object is bound to a specific window (`UpdateData()` creates a new one and calls `DoDataExchange()`). So no need to make the child's `DoDataExchange()` public or the parent dailog class a friend. Below is the code I wrote and tested - and seems to work as it should.

```
void CMFCApplication3Dlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog* pActiveDlg = nullptr;
    switch (m_tabReportMode.GetCurSel())
    {
        case 0: pActiveDlg = &m_dlgList; break;
        case 1: pActiveDlg = &m_dlgReview; break;
        case 2: pActiveDlg = &m_dlgSummary; break;
    }

    // Call UpdateData() of the currently active child dialog. Stop if validation fails
    // NOTE: do not change the order of evaluation of the terms below!
    if (pActiveDlg && !pActiveDlg->UpdateData(pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate) && pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate)
        pDX->Fail(); // Throws an exception, and doesn't validate the parent dialog's controls

    // Proceed normally with the parent dialog's DDX/DDV
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TAB1, m_ctlTab1);
}
```

**Note:** Please consider modifying the code above, so as to call `UpdateData()` for all child dialogs (if they have been created), instead of the currently active one only. That is, *should the user be allowed to enter "wrong" values in a dialog on a tab that is not the currently active one?* (don't know your UI design though).

Comment: Thank you. In my case I only save the settings for the active child dialog. I did make two adjustments to your code though. 1. I changed the  `pActiveDlg` to a `CDialogEx*`. 2. I got an exception when I ran it because `m_tabReportMode` was not valid. So I wrapped all the custom code in a `if (m_tabReportMode.GetSafeHwnd() != nullptr)` call. Now all is good.

Comment: So the key difference (to the article's suggestion you linked) is the call of `UpdateData()` instead of `DoDataExchange()` for the child, which creates a new `pDX` object (you can see this in the MFC sources). As for using `CDialog*` I made it this way so as to be more generic; but it doesn't really matter, it could have been even a `CWnd*` and still work the same (`UpdateData() is a non-virtual method of `CWnd` and for the virtual ones the overridden methods would be called). The `m_tabReportMode` not having been created yet is something I couldn't check in my test because I didn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I have come up with:

```
void CPublicTalksSetupDlg::UpdateData(BOOL bSaveAndValidate)
{
    const auto current = m_tabReportMode.GetCurSel();

    if (current == 0)
    {
        m_dlgList.UpdateData(bSaveAndValidate);
    }
    else if (current == 1)
    {
        m_dlgReview.UpdateData(bSaveAndValidate);
    }
    else if (current == 2)
    {
        m_dlgSummary.UpdateData(bSaveAndValidate);
    }

    __super::UpdateData(bSaveAndValidate);
}
```

It works well.

---

Addressing the comment … this shows the dangers of using ChatGPT because it said:

[image]

It clearly stated to use `void` but I can now see via intellisense that it should have a return type of `BOOL`. So I have adjusted the function as:

```
BOOL CPublicTalksSetupDlg::UpdateData(BOOL bSaveAndValidate)
{
    const auto current = m_tabReportMode.GetCurSel();

    if (current == 0)
    {
        m_dlgList.UpdateData(bSaveAndValidate);
    }
    else if (current == 1)
    {
        m_dlgReview.UpdateData(bSaveAndValidate);
    }
    else if (current == 2)
    {
        m_dlgSummary.UpdateData(bSaveAndValidate);
    }

    return __super::UpdateData(bSaveAndValidate);
}
```

Comment: So you have one child dialog active at a time and call `UpdateData()` for that one only, OK with this. Something that is not very much OK tho, is that `UpdateData()` returns `BOOL` (`TRUE` if DDV validation was successful). You define a `void` function here. I would expect the compiler to complain about this (some C++ expert, pls help). Maybe if the child's `UpdateData()` call returns `FALSE` do not call the `__super` one? Not sure what happens if the framework displays those "Validation Error" message boxes, you would need to check - `OnOK()` should not close the dialog if validation fails.

Comment: Tough luck, just checked the documentation and the actual MFC sources, and found that... `UpdateData()` is **NOT** vritual! Maybe that's why the compiler didn't complain. So... no override here, and the ChatGPT suggestion is rather wrong. I apologize for that. I'll investigate it a little more.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I don't see this to be an issue. My `UpdataData` is being triggered. It is executing and calling the child ones. Maybe their is an aspect I have not considered.  I appreciate your investigating and see what you glean.

Comment: It's not an override though, it hides the original function. Just tested and found that `OnOK()` calls the original one. Maybe in your implementation of `OnOK()` (or somewhere else) you have an explicit call to `CPublicTalksSetupDlg::UpdateData()` - this would call the new function, which is not an actual override.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I see. What if we revert to DoDataExchange? And in there test if each child has a valid safe handle to window, and if so call it’s UpdateData, passing the bool param.